# CodeIgniter safe_mailto function does not obfuscate email address

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, obfuscation

I've used `safe_mailto()` function in CodeIgniter 3.1.0 but it seems it does not work as it is described in documents. This is my code :

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('url');
echo safe_mailto('myemail@site.com');
?>
```

As document says, this function obfuscated version of the mailto tag using ordinal numbers written with JavaScript to help prevent the e-mail address from being harvested by spam bots. But what I get as the result (by copying the link destination) is just the plain form of written email address.
Is there anything missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does work. Check your page HTML source.

Load your page with the safe mailto, then view the page source, find the link, it is not there. Javascript is decoding it for the screen, but a url scraper will not see it, as in the source it is all javascript.

Link coded as:

```
<?php echo safe_mailto('me@my-site.com', 'Click Here to Contact Me'); ?>
```

Link appears as:

```
Click Here to Contact Me
```

Inspect element appears as:

```
<a href="mailto:me@my-site.com">Click Here to Contact Me</a>
```

Source code is actually:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var l=new Array();
l[0] = '>';
l[1] = 'a';
l[2] = '/';
l[3] = '<';
l[4] = '|101';
l[5] = '|77';
l[6] = '|32';
l[7] = '|116';
l[8] = '|99';
l[9] = '|97';
l[10] = '|116';
l[11] = '|110';
l[12] = '|111';
l[13] = '|67';
l[14] = '|32';
l[15] = '|111';
l[16] = '|116';
l[17] = '|32';
l[18] = '|101';
l[19] = '|114';
l[20] = '|101';
l[21] = '|72';
l[22] = '|32';
l[23] = '|107';
l[24] = '|99';
l[25] = '|105';
l[26] = '|108';
l[27] = '|67';
l[28] = '>';
l[29] = '"';
l[30] = '|109';
l[31] = '|111';
l[32] = '|99';
l[33] = '|46';
l[34] = '|101';
l[35] = '|116';
l[36] = '|105';
l[37] = '|115';
l[38] = '|45';
l[39] = '|121';
l[40] = '|109';
l[41] = '|64';
l[42] = '|101';
l[43] = '|109';
l[44] = ':';
l[45] = 'o';
l[46] = 't';
l[47] = 'l';
l[48] = 'i';
l[49] = 'a';
l[50] = 'm';
l[51] = '"';
l[52] = '=';
l[53] = 'f';
l[54] = 'e';
l[55] = 'r';
l[56] = 'h';
l[57] = ' ';
l[58] = 'a';
l[59] = '<';

for (var i = l.length-1; i >= 0; i=i-1) {
    if (l[i].substring(0, 1) === '|')  document.write("&#"+unescape(l[i].substring(1))+";");
        else document.write(unescape(l[i]));
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

Hence it is obfuscated.

Hope that helps.

Paul.

Comment: Thank you PaulD. That's right. I had checked it with inspect element and email address was visible. But in the source there is no email ...